# Inconsistent Cookies between www and non-www URLs

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie, nginx

I have a site with some cookies issues where going to a non-www URL will set cookies that prevents customers from logging in. I have found other questions that refer to the cookies settings as the solution, but this isn't working for me. So...

`exmaple.com/login` requested `->` cookie set for `.example.com`. This prevents logins.

`www.exmaple.com/login` requested `->` cookie set for `.www.example.com`. This works.

I've tried settings the *cookie path* and *cookie domain* in the system config without any success. For now, I'm redirecting all non-www page request to the www URL to deal with this issue, but is there another way to do this on the Magento configuration-level instead of the web server?

We're using nginx, Redis, and on CE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big issue is that Magento expects the website host name part of the URL to be what is listed in your BaseURLs.

So for example, if you have set Magento to serve out the site as `www.example.com` and someone comes in on `example.com`, Magento creates a session and a cookie for `example.com`, does a redirect to the BaseURL `www.example.com` and creates a new session.

The browser now has two cookies set and UX quickly goes downhill from there with cookie/session confusion shutting things down in weird ways.

Your best bet is to never let Magento get involved in this process. Use .htaccess rules or in your case, nginx rules to keep Magento in the dark and never see the non-BaseURL host name.

Set your cookie path/domain to match the choice made in your rules.

An added advantage also is that your customer "helpdesk" calls tend to go way down along with the misery of telling them how to delete cookies and history to attempt making the website function for them. Been there, done that, the teeshirt was no good and the experience no fun.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is:

1. set your base url = `http://www.example.com/`
2. set redirect to base url = `no`
3. in `.htaccess` rewrite `example.com` to `www.example.com`

you dont even have to touch cookie settings.
this is it.